# Optional permission for filesystem

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

Is it possible to mention `filesystem` as an optional permission requested by `chrome.permissions.request` API (for Chrome apps)?

My JS code includes :

```
document.getElementById('savebtn').addEventListener('click',
    function () {
        chrome.permissions.request({ permissions: ["fileSystem"] },
            function (granted) {
                if (granted) {
                    chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({ type: 'openDirectory' },
                        function (entry) {
                            ...
                        });
                }
            });
    });
```

but I get an error around `chrome.fileSystem` in the above code that says :

```
... extensions::fileSystem:11: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getFileBindingsForApi' of undefined{TypeError: Cannot read property 'getFileBindingsForApi' of undefined
```

My `manifest.json` file includes :

```
  "optional_permissions": [
    {"fileSystem": ["write", "retainEntries", "directory"]}
  ],
```

Comment: @apsillers Did not know about that list; can you add that as an actual answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should request the `fileSystem.directory` permission as well if you want to use `chooseEntry` with type `openDirectory`. This can be done as follows:

```js
chrome.permissions.request({
    permissions: [
        'fileSystem',
        'fileSystem.write',
        'fileSystem.retainEntries',
        'fileSystem.directory'
    ]
}, function(granted) {
    if (granted) { /* use chrome.fileSystem API */ }
});
```

Before Chrome 45, there was a bug that causes the error in your question when you access the `chrome.fileSystem` API after getting the `fileSystem` permission for the first time. In Chrome 44, an error message was printed to the console, while earlier versions caused the extension to crash (https://crbug.com/489723).
To work around this bug, put the `fileSystem` permission in the required set of permissions, i.e. have the following in manifest.json:

```js
"optional_permissions": [
    {"fileSystem": ["write", "retainEntries", "directory"]}
],
"permissions": [
    "fileSystem"
],
```

The fileSystem permission doesn't add any install warning, so marking this permission as required is not a big deal.

Comment: What? The filesystem permission shows a "Write to files and folders that you open in the application" warning.

Comment: @Daniel Only if you also include the extra permissions like `fileSystem.write` or `{"filesystem":["write"]}`.

Comment: So you could then request the other filesystem permissions optionally without error?

Comment: @DanielHerr Apps can always request these permissions without an error (provided that the request was initiated by a user gesture). The error in this Q&A is a bug in Chrome and its root cause is not the optional permission system.